# Open a Bootstrap Modal from C# asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have a big issue, I am trying to open a modal from c#, however I have read all the stack overflow answers and question but any has helped me out. 
Here’s the problem.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            getProduct();
            //ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "openModal();", true);
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "mdlError", "$('#mdlError').modal();", true);
        }
    }
```

this works when I use a master page in .net, however when I run the app, nothing happens, the code just runs but it doesn't crash. I debug this piece of code and it seems there is a problem:

```
RegisterStartupScript   error CS0428: Cannot convert method group 'RegisterStartupScript' to non-delegate type 'object'. Did you intend to invoke the method?
```

Can somebody help me out please?
I am using Asp.NET and C#.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: To begin with, calling a script from server side isn't a good practice.
Why not create an external js file and call modal? or in the page itself?

Comment: How could I call the modal if there is any error through the execution of some method?

Comment: That's because you are attempting to call modal via RegisterStartupScript. My suggestion is to create an external js file that calls the modal?

Comment: Would you please provide some example of it?

Answer (score 0):

As Andrew suggested you should consider defining a client side function to open the pop up.

```
function openModal() {
   $('#mdlError').modal({ show: true });
}
```

Then call this function from code behind

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "openModal();", true);
```